# AngularJs call $http inline method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have no experience with angularjs , just started using angularjs.

I have an input div, I want to call http.get but inside the HTML in this div focus change, I have written this example :

```
<input  ng-focus="$http.get('http://server/GeneralHandler.ashx?method=GetDataFromHandler&Parameters=5,633,2015-12-12,2015-12-12,0').then( function(res) {alert(res);},function(err) {alert(err);})" id='VacationTypeID' class='details-value' ng-model='VacationTypeID' name='VacationTypeID' ng-init="VacationTypeID= '88'" />`
```

But when trying to run this code I am getting this error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 143 of the expression [$http.get('http://server/GeneralHandler.ashx?method=GetDataFromHandler&Parameters=5,633,2015-12-12,2015-12-12,0').then( function(res) {alert(res);},function(err) {alert(err);})] starting at [{alert(res);},function(err) {alert(err);})].http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B)%5D&p2=143&p3=%24http.get('http%3A%2F%2surver%2FGeneralHandler.ashx%3Fmethod%3DGetDataFromHandler%26Parameters%3D5%2C633%2C2015-12-12%2C2015-12-12%2C0').then(NaNunction(res)%20%7Balert(res)%3B%7D%2Cfunction(err)%20%7Balert(err)%3B%7D)&p4=%7Balert(res)%3B%7D%2Cfunction(err)%20%7Balert(err)%3B%7D)
at http://localhost:4400/lib/angular/angular.js:68:12
at Object.AST.throwError (http://localhost:4400/lib/angular/angular.js:13057:11)
at Object.AST.consume (http://localhost:4400/lib/angular/angular.js:13069:12)
at Object.AST.primary (http://localhost:4400/lib/angular/angular.js:12967:14)
at Object.AST.unary (http://localhost:4400/lib/angular/angular.js:12940:19)
at Object.AST.multiplicative (http://localhost:4400/lib/angular/angular.js:12927:21)
at Object.AST.additive (http://localhost:4400/lib/angular/angular.js:12918:21)
at Object.AST.relational (http://localhost:4400/lib/angular/angular.js:12909:21)
at Object.AST.equality (http://localhost:4400/lib/angular/angular.js:12900:21)
at Object.AST.logicalAND (http://localhost:4400/lib/angular/angular.js:12892:21)`
```

I want to write inline method calling http request in ng-focus, I don't know in advance what this method will be, I will retrieve its content from my back-end.

Any help please ?

Comment: I suggest  you to simplify the code to be inserted from your back-end. You should create in your scope functions wrapping the $http.get with all its handlers.

Comment: @beaver I dont know the code to be insterted, it will be dynamic based on the displayed contents.

Comment: $http is a has to be dependency injected. You cant use directly in the template. Its the controller job to get the $http handler and do the required logic.

Comment: @Nirus Coul you please give me an example how i can achieve this ?

Comment: can you paste a fiddler link for your code? Well also take a look at @beaver answer it should work.

Answer (score 0):

But really you can't use this code in your controller?

```
$scope.httpGet = function(url) {
    $http.get(url).then( 
        function(res) {
            alert(res);
        },
        function(err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    );
}
```

and modify HTML...

```
<input ng-focus="httpGet('http://server/GeneralHandler.ashx?method=GetDataFromHandler&Parameters=5,633,2015-12-12,2015-12-12,0')" id='VacationTypeID' class='details-value' ng-model='VacationTypeID' name='VacationTypeID' ng-init="VacationTypeID= '88'" />
```

so you can allow your backend to pass the right url (but eventually other parameters for `$scope.httpGet()` )